# GridView field modified in RowDataBound is not sorted

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I'm running into a problem with programmatically changing the Text and NavigateUrl properties of a HyperLink control during the RowDataBound event of a GridView when I sort that GridView. The HyperLink control is in a TemplateField. On initial load of the GridView, the Text and NavigateURL properties are displayed as expected, but upon sorting, the order of the cells containing the HyperLink control do not change along with the other data in the GridView. The rest of the GridView sorts as expected, but the TemplateField in question appears not to move.

I suspect that the RowDataBound event is not fired on sort, but I'm not sure where to go from here. I am not using SqlDataSource due to SQL Server 2000.

Here is the GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvOpenOrders" runat="server" CssClass="gridview" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="gvOpenOrders_Sorting" OnRowDataBound="gvOpenOrders_RowDataBound">
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="altrow" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbSO" runat="server" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="csono" Text="SO"></asp:LinkButton>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="hlSO" runat="server"><%# Eval("csono") %></asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle CssClass="ta-center" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbCustno" runat="server" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="ccustno" Text="Cust No."></asp:LinkButton>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("ccustno") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle CssClass="ta-center" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

This is how I am DataBinding the GridView in Page_Load if(!IsPostBack):

```
private void BindGridView()
{
    string sqlOpenSO;
    string sortDirection = "", sortExpression = "";
    sqlOpenSO = // SQL query goes here (removed for post)

    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlOpenSO, connectionString))
    {
        sda.Fill(ds);
        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            DataView dv = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            if (ViewState["SortDirection"] != null)
            {
                sortDirection = ViewState["SortDirection"].ToString();
            }
            if (ViewState["SortExpression"] != null)
            {
                sortExpression = ViewState["SortExpression"].ToString();
                dv.Sort = string.Concat(sortExpression, " ", sortDirection);
            }

            gvOpenOrders.DataSource = dv;
            gvOpenOrders.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

With the following OnSorting method:

```
protected void gvOpenOrders_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    if (ViewState["SortDirection"] == null || ViewState["SortExpression"].ToString() != e.SortExpression)
    {
        ViewState["SortDirection"] = "ASC";
        gvOpenOrders.PageIndex = 0;
    }
    else if (ViewState["SortDirection"].ToString() == "ASC")
    {
        ViewState["SortDirection"] = "DESC";
    }
    else if (ViewState["SortDirection"].ToString() == "DESC")
    {
        ViewState["SortDirection"] = "ASC";
    }

    ViewState["SortExpression"] = e.SortExpression;
    BindGridView();
}
```

And the following RowDataBound method:

```
protected void gvOpenOrders_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        HyperLink hlSO = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("hlSO");
        hlSO.NavigateUrl = "<<URL removed for post>>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[e.Row.RowIndex]["csono"].ToString();
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ds.Tables[0].Rows[e.Row.RowIndex]["crevision"].ToString()))
        {
            hlSO.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[e.Row.RowIndex]["csono"].ToString() + "-" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[e.Row.RowIndex]["crevision"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            hlSO.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[e.Row.RowIndex]["csono"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your sorting comes before you bind the GridView. First, you sort the datasourse, then it is bound and only then the row is modified. Think of ways to rearrange your logic within the Life Cycle. For example, concider modifying data in the datasource before sorting, then sort and databind.

Comment: @NikitaSilverstruk: He does not sort the datasource. He only databinds the GridView `if(!IsPostBack)`, on postbacks from sorting actions he changes the sort-column and direction in Viewstate, then he sorts the DataSource according to these values and DatBinds the GridView again. I cannot see the problem. 

@OP: Have you used the debugger to see what happens?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, what I meant is that the OP sorts the `DataView` in his `BindGridView()` method: `dv.Sort = string.Concat(sortExpression, " ", sortDirection);`, then the GridView is bound and only then the value of a bound row is changed. Here, sorting comes before the value is changed. Or am I missing something? EDIT: I am frazing myself incorreclty... Doesn't Sorting comes before binding in th eLife Cycle?

Comment: I assume that the `DataSource` of his grid is causing the problem. He is using a `DataView` which can be sorted with `DataView.Sort`. However, note that the underlying `DataTable` remains unchanged. But he is accessing the (unsorted)`DataRows` of the `DataTable` in `RowDataBound`.  So either order in the database itself which is also more efficient or order the `DataTable`, for example via `Linq-To-DataSet` (`OrderBy(...).CopyToDataTable()`).

Comment: Thanks, guys. I redesigned the process to order in the database and everything is working as expected. Post your suggestion as an answer, and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this natively in GridView without needing TemplateFields:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvOpenOrders" runat="server" CssClass="gridview" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="gvOpenOrders_Sorting" OnRowDataBound="gvOpenOrders_RowDataBound">
            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="altrow" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFormatString="<<URL removed for post>>{0}{1}"
                     DataNavigateUrlFields="csono, crevision" >

                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbCustno" runat="server" CommandName="Sort" 
                             CommandArgument="ccustno" Text="Cust No."></asp:LinkButton>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("ccustno") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle CssClass="ta-center" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Sorting and everything else should continue working natively and I think this will avoid your sort issue.

Try it out and let me know how it works.  Oh, and this should allow you to get rid of the code in OnRowDataBound.

Comment: Sounds like a good suggestion, but I also need to do some conditional formatting based on cell data, so I need to get a handle on doing this (or things like it) through the code-behind.